# How does this part of the ASOP makefile work?

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make, android-source

I am trying to modify the AOSP build system to run a script after 'make dist'

I have code that does what I want it to.... but I don't really understand it and would love an explanation and what is happening.  The file I am looking at is:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build.git/+/master/core/distdir.mk

```
.PHONY: dist
dist: ;

dist_goal := $(strip $(filter dist,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
MAKECMDGOALS := $(strip $(filter-out dist,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifeq (,$(strip $(filter-out $(INTERNAL_MODIFIER_TARGETS),$(MAKECMDGOALS))))
# The commandline was something like "make dist" or "make dist showcommands".
# Add a dependency on a real target.
dist: $(DEFAULT_GOAL)
endif
```

The part that is confusing me is how there are two definitions for dist: but no warnings. If I had a recipe on to the second dist: target it will generate a warning about dist being redefined.  What is the point of this second target?

Comment: You can define as many separate rules for the same target as you want, AS LONG AS only one of them has a recipe.  All the prerequisites for all the rules are combined together into one list of prerequisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dist: ;
```

just says, "to update `dist` target, do nothing".  Without this, if the second part were not present, Make would not know what how to make `dist`.  (In fact the "empty recipe" here `;` is not really needed - it is only needed for specific situations, and this is not one of them - without it, you would still be doing "nothing" here)

If the second part is present:

```
dist: $(DEFAULT_GOAL)
```

that means, "to update `dist` target, update `$(DEFAULT_GOAL)`

If both parts are present, we update `$(DEFAULT_GOAL)` and then do nothing more.

In general, you can have one explicit rule for a target with a recipe present (here, the recipe is just `;`), and then you can have other rules without recipes, they just establish additional dependencies as they are noted.  There is no ambiguity which recipe to execute and Make is happy.

Comment: I believe that the "empty recipe" is here to emphasize that in no other place some non-dummy recipe is not present for `dest`.

Comment: Between this and MadScientist this makes sense.  Thank you very much for clearing it up!

Comment: Well, it is good that I wrote mine first. If a Make question has already been answered by MadScientist, it is pointless to try and improve upon it.  I am not sarcastic.